# Google Web Designer - Adding an "active" class to swipe gallery feed items?

Tags: events, components, gallery, google-web-designer

I'm creating a dynamic adword banner for my company where I'm trying to make a scrolling gallery of product images using the swipe gallery component. I'm looking for a way to add a custom class (let's just say class="active" in this case) to the img element when a user scrolls or uses the prev/next buttons. Is there a way using the events tool to add in a custom class like that?

To be more specific, when a user clicks on a prev/next button or slides, the current image they're looking at will have the "active" class on it which will apply styles to highlight that image amongst the others.